# Ruby MSSQL query error message not found

Tags: sql-server, ruby

```
result = client.execute("SELECT TOP (2000) node_id FROM  [td].[node] WHERE  (node_id = 220)")
result.each do |row|
  if result.nil?
    puts 'Node id could not found'
  else
    puts row
    puts 'Node is found on the database'
  end
end
```

I'm using `Ruby` and the `tiny_tds gem` for my script.  On the mssql database, node_id 220 does not exist. When I run this script it passes, but I don't see the output message 'Node id could not found'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you even goes into the loop? If result is nil (or empty), you will not have any row object to go into the loop.

```
result = client.execute("SELECT TOP (2000) node_id FROM  [td].[node] WHERE  (node_id = 220)")
result.each do |row|
    puts 'I came into the loop'
  if result.nil?
    puts 'Node id could not found'
  else
    puts row
    puts 'Node is found on the database'
  end
end
```

I'm quite sure this could would produce nothing neither in your case. You should test whether result is empty outside the loop.

```
result = client.execute("SELECT TOP (2000) node_id FROM  [td].[node] WHERE  (node_id = 220)")
#test here whether result is empty or not
result.each do |row|
    puts row
    puts 'Node is found on the database'
end
```

Comment: what will return `if result.empty?`

Comment: Probably what you wants, but I don't know for sure the type of your result object. You can test.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the readme: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

The client will always return a `Result` object  - so even if the query found no matching rows in the DB, the result will NOT be `nil`.